# Bootstrap 3.0 Nav Bar turns Transparent or White

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When my Navigation menu is not Inverse I get this outcome.

[image: Non Inverse]

But When I set it to inverse I get this outcome.

[image: Inverse]

I am using the core Bootstrap file. And my navigation system code is.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="animbrand"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Welcome</a>   
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

        </li>
```

And My navigation continues after this.

What may cause the problem? I would like to not inverse but keep it simple. I am not using any custom Skins (Bootwatch) nor anything.

Yes All my CSS, JS, IMGS are linked correctly (scr)

My Head code just in case.

```
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Welcome</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS for the template -->
<link href="css/image.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/skin.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any thoughts on this? I have spent the entire day trying to figure this out.

Please note: Even without my custom code, css and js the nav looks the same.

Comment: "navbar navbar-default" needs to be the class of the `nav`

Answer (score 0):

That's the intended result of getting rid of .navbar-inverse. If you want to change the color, tack on another class name after .navbar-inverse and over-ride the attributes for background color and what else. But if you see with the examples from GetBootstrap, getting rid of .navbar-inverse will turn the background transparent.